# Error after installing Anaconda 2: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, python-3.6, fatal-error, multiple-versions

When trying to run a program in python from the terminal I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Current thread 0x00007fffb68a93c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

I am currently running Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) and think this problem may have to do with also having Anaconda 2 installed. Could someone help me figure out what the cause is and how I can remedy this?

I'd also be interested in knowing more tips about how to use Anaconda 2 and 3 concurrently so that this doesn't happen again.

Comment: I ran into this issue today with Anaconda3. Removing and then reinstalling Anaconda fixed it. I kept my conda environments by moving anaconda3/envs somewhere else, deleting the anaconda3 directory, then moving envs back into the new anaconda3 dir after install. Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trouble shooting w/ you, it looks like reinstalling anaconda (from the version 3.6 choice on the web) crossed some wires.

For others either...

1) Use your original installment and make a python3 environment. To do this change your .bash_profile to only include 
`export PATH="/Users/<username>/anaconda2/bin:$PATH` 
and perhaps remove or move the 
`/Users/<username>/anaconda3` 
directory to a new name. Then make a new environment using the original anaconda(with python version 2) that fetches and uses Python 3.6:

`conda create -n mypython3environment python=3.6`
where "mypython3environment" is some name you want when you use python 3.6
then to use it in your project - go to your project's directory and type:

`source activate mypython3environment`

2) Do a clean install. The other option is to cut out the anaconda stuff from your .bash_profile, remove or move the anaconda2/ and anaconda3 directories and the .bash_profile.pysave file and try to reinstall from the anaconda webpage.

Overall - you need to install anaconda once - then use `conda create` and `source activate <environment name>` to make then use environments, respectively, with your Python version of choice, whether it is a Python 2 or 3 version.

See [Anaconda's Managing Environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) and the [cheatsheet](https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf)